# Access endpoint /email/verify

Tags: fusionauth

We implemented the endpoints as documented on https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/tutorials/login-theme chapter 6. It worked until version 1.6.1. With version 1.7.2 the endpoints do not work anymore. 
Setup used:
Docker based setup. Fusionauth-app: fusionauth/fusionauth-app:1.7.2 Fusionauth-search: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.1.
MariaDB 10.3 as Database

The call is:

```
{server}:9011/email/send?email=<a valid email>
```

Reponse: 500 Internal Server Error

The logs (as visible to docker): show no direct entry response to the call

Log file entries which might be related:

```
2019-07-25T02:34:40.546204161Z Jul 25, 2019 2:34:40.545 AM WARN  org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionMappingWorkflow - The action class [io.fusionauth.app.action.api.email.SendAction] does not have a valid execute method for the HTTP method [GET],
2019-07-25T06:11:06.645779691Z Jul 25, 2019 6:11:06.645 AM WARN  org.primeframework.mvc.message.l10n.ResourceBundleMessageProvider - Message could not be found for the URI [/oauth2/register] and key [[couldNotConvert]metaData.device.type],
2019-07-25T06:13:22.140462316Z Jul 25, 2019 6:13:22.140 AM WARN  org.primeframework.mvc.message.l10n.ResourceBundleMessageProvider - Message could not be found for the URI [/password/forgot] and key [[couldNotConvert]metaData.device.type],
2019-07-25T06:13:26.162407084Z Jul 25, 2019 6:13:26.162 AM WARN  org.primeframework.mvc.message.l10n.ResourceBundleMessageProvider - Message could not be found for the URI [/password/forgot] and key [[couldNotConvert]metaData.device.type],
2019-07-25T06:13:34.342834324Z Jul 25, 2019 6:13:34.342 AM WARN  org.primeframework.mvc.message.l10n.ResourceBundleMessageProvider - Message could not be found for the URI [/password/forgot] and key [[couldNotConvert]metaData.device.type],
2019-07-25T06:16:08.538471081Z Jul 25, 2019 6:16:08.537 AM WARN  org.primeframework.mvc.message.l10n.ResourceBundleMessageProvider - Message could not be found for the URI [/password/forgot] and key [[couldNotConvert]metaData.device.type],
```

Another Log file stack trace which might be related:

```
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867391651Z 26-Jul-2019 06:48:55.866 INFO [http-nio-9011-exec-8] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header,
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867418300Z  Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.,
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867428210Z  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens,
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867431593Z  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:428),
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867434845Z  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:687),
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867437925Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66),
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867441242Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790),
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867444391Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468),
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867447189Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49),
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867458014Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149),
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867460994Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624),
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867463789Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61),
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867466682Z  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748),
2019-07-26T06:48:55.867469439Z ,
```

A day later:

```
2019-07-27T08:05:55.308423552Z Jul 27, 2019 8:05:55.308 AM WARN  org.primeframework.mvc.message.l10n.ResourceBundleMessageProvider - Message could not be found for the URI [/oauth2/register] and key [[couldNotConvert]metaData.device.type],
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170033158Z Jul 27, 2019 8:38:05.169 AM ERROR io.fusionauth.app.primeframework.error.ExceptionExceptionHandler - An unhandled exception was thrown,
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170068651Z java.lang.NullPointerException: null,
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170072725Z  at io.fusionauth.app.action.oauth2.CompleteRegistrationAction.get(CompleteRegistrationAction.java:39),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170076142Z  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170079300Z  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170082582Z  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170085611Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:436),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170088690Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.execute(DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.java:84),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170092047Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.perform(DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.java:64),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170095236Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170098568Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.validation.DefaultValidationWorkflow.perform(DefaultValidationWorkflow.java:47),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170102115Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170105395Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.security.DefaultSecurityWorkflow.perform(DefaultSecurityWorkflow.java:60),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170108717Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170111893Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultPostParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultPostParameterWorkflow.java:50),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170115008Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170118063Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.content.DefaultContentWorkflow.perform(DefaultContentWorkflow.java:52),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170121169Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170124319Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultParameterWorkflow.java:57),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170138274Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170142560Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultURIParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultURIParameterWorkflow.java:102),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170146600Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170149712Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.scope.DefaultScopeRetrievalWorkflow.perform(DefaultScopeRetrievalWorkflow.java:58),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170170332Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170173947Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.message.DefaultMessageWorkflow.perform(DefaultMessageWorkflow.java:45),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170177095Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170180358Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionMappingWorkflow.perform(DefaultActionMappingWorkflow.java:126),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170183318Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170186451Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.StaticResourceWorkflow.perform(StaticResourceWorkflow.java:97),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170189547Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170192805Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.RequestBodyWorkflow.perform(RequestBodyWorkflow.java:89),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170196039Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170199572Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.security.DefaultSavedRequestWorkflow.perform(DefaultSavedRequestWorkflow.java:57),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170202401Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170205322Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.DefaultMVCWorkflow.perform(DefaultMVCWorkflow.java:91),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170208401Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.DefaultWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(DefaultWorkflowChain.java:44),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170211878Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.FilterWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(FilterWorkflowChain.java:50),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170214928Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.PrimeFilter.doFilter(PrimeFilter.java:84),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170217981Z  at com.inversoft.maintenance.servlet.MaintenanceModePrimeFilter.doFilter(MaintenanceModePrimeFilter.java:59),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170221571Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170224915Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170228148Z  at com.inversoft.servlet.UTF8Filter.doFilter(UTF8Filter.java:27),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170235845Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170239160Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170242710Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170245888Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170249164Z  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170252418Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170255696Z  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170258802Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170262048Z  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170264981Z  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170268273Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170271761Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170275184Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170278451Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170282255Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170285565Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170288982Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61),
2019-07-27T08:38:05.170292486Z  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.799948980Z Jul 27, 2019 8:38:40.799 AM ERROR io.fusionauth.app.primeframework.error.ExceptionExceptionHandler - An unhandled exception was thrown,
2019-07-27T08:38:40.799983887Z java.lang.NullPointerException: null,
2019-07-27T08:38:40.799987658Z  at io.fusionauth.app.action.oauth2.CompleteRegistrationAction.get(CompleteRegistrationAction.java:39),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.799990430Z  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.799992794Z  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.799995136Z  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.799997274Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:436),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.799999394Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.execute(DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.java:84),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800011430Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.perform(DefaultActionInvocationWorkflow.java:64),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800013831Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800016117Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.validation.DefaultValidationWorkflow.perform(DefaultValidationWorkflow.java:47),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800018388Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800020565Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.security.DefaultSecurityWorkflow.perform(DefaultSecurityWorkflow.java:60),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800022740Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800025003Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultPostParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultPostParameterWorkflow.java:50),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800027119Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800029296Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.content.DefaultContentWorkflow.perform(DefaultContentWorkflow.java:52),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800031398Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800033637Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultParameterWorkflow.java:57),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800036342Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800039803Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.DefaultURIParameterWorkflow.perform(DefaultURIParameterWorkflow.java:102),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800044845Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800048322Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.scope.DefaultScopeRetrievalWorkflow.perform(DefaultScopeRetrievalWorkflow.java:58),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800051735Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800055209Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.message.DefaultMessageWorkflow.perform(DefaultMessageWorkflow.java:45),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800058645Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800062007Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.action.DefaultActionMappingWorkflow.perform(DefaultActionMappingWorkflow.java:126),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800064226Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800066306Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.StaticResourceWorkflow.perform(StaticResourceWorkflow.java:97),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800068446Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800070578Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.parameter.RequestBodyWorkflow.perform(RequestBodyWorkflow.java:89),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800072722Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800078310Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.security.DefaultSavedRequestWorkflow.perform(DefaultSavedRequestWorkflow.java:57),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800080554Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.SubWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(SubWorkflowChain.java:43),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800082666Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.DefaultMVCWorkflow.perform(DefaultMVCWorkflow.java:91),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800084818Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.workflow.DefaultWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(DefaultWorkflowChain.java:44),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800086964Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.FilterWorkflowChain.continueWorkflow(FilterWorkflowChain.java:50),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800089034Z  at org.primeframework.mvc.servlet.PrimeFilter.doFilter(PrimeFilter.java:84),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800091174Z  at com.inversoft.maintenance.servlet.MaintenanceModePrimeFilter.doFilter(MaintenanceModePrimeFilter.java:59),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800093532Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800095790Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800097868Z  at com.inversoft.servlet.UTF8Filter.doFilter(UTF8Filter.java:27),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800100310Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800102484Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800104680Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800106875Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800109334Z  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800111424Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800113554Z  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800115655Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800117734Z  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800119758Z  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800122630Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800126626Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800130073Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800133327Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800142280Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800145423Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800147550Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61),
2019-07-27T08:38:40.800149681Z  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748),
```

Comment: What is not working specifically? Do you see exceptions in the logs causing something not to render correctly?

Comment: I use the docker based setup. 
Fusionauth-app: fusionauth/fusionauth-app:1.7.2
Fusionauth-search: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.1

The call is: {server}:9011/email/send?email=<a valid email>
Reponse: 500 Internal Server Error
The logs (as visible to docker): show no entry
A fusionauth-app log as /usr/local/fusionauth/logs/fusionauth-app.log does not exist in the container

Comment: If you get a `500` there will be an exception in the log, when running in Docker the logs will be sent to standard out, or wherever you've capturing them in Docker.  If you can capture the exception and post it here that will be very helpful.

Comment: There is no immediate log entry following the http request. I found the following entries which might be related:
2019-07-25T06:11:06.645779691Z Jul 25, 2019 6:11:06.645 AM WARN  org.primeframework.mvc.message.l10n.ResourceBundleMessageProvider - Message could not be found for the URI [/oauth2/register] and key [[couldNotConvert]metaData.device.type],
2019-07-25T06:13:22.140462316Z Jul 25, 2019 6:13:22.140 AM WARN  org.primeframework.mvc.message.l10n.ResourceBundleMessageProvider - Message could not be found for the URI [/password/forgot] and key [[couldNotConvert]metaData.device.type]

Comment: Those warnings don't look too interesting, are you using a theme and if so have you modified any templates?

Comment: If this is the same issue as https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/244 let's work it there.

Comment: I am using the login theme but it is not (yet) customized.
We can use issue 244 to follow on, it looks like the same issue